# How is entropy calculated in a Constant Temperature process, when a gas is compressed from from $p_1$ to $p_2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, entropy

Entropy for constant temperature process, when instead of volumes, pressures changes from $p_1$ to $p_2$?

Answer (score 1):

The formula involving volume for enetropy change at constant temperature, $$\Delta S=nR\ln\left(\frac{V_2}{V_1}\right)$$For an ideal gas at constant temperature, $$P1V_1=P_2V_2$$or $$\frac{V_2}{V_1}=\frac{P_1}{P_2}$$